# how to display total number of course?

Tags: php

i am developing website in core php . so in website there is categories inside which i am adding courses i wants to display the number of course like dis
Reference link:-https://stageserver.co/ppcl/courses.php  (check Browse All Categories section)

i have created function (function.php) :

```
function get_count_course(){
    global $dbh;
    $getregcourse = "SELECT * FROM courses 
                    WHERE course_cat_id = :id 
                    ORDER BY date_added DESC";

    $setregCourse = $dbh->prepare($getregcourse);
    $setregCourse->bindParam(':id', $id);

    $setregCourse->execute();

    $courses = $setregCourse->fetchAll();

    return $courses;
}
```

and wants to display in template(courses.php) :-

```
<section class="ppcl__allbrowser">
    <div class="wrp-box">
        <h3 class="ppcl__educenterheading ppcl--colorblack">
            Browse All Categories
        </h3>
        <div class="ppcl__allbrowsercolunm">
<?php
$category = get_course_categories();
$Courses=get_count_course();

foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
?>
            <div class="ppcl__allbrowser--item">
                <a href="" class="ppcl__allbrowser-name <?php echo ($key == 0 ? 
'course_active':'');?>" data-evalz="<?php echo $value['course_cat_id'];?>" 
id="category_<?php echo $value['course_cat_id'];?>"  > <?php echo $value['course_cat_name']; ?></a>

                    <div class="bredge border-left">
                        <div class="number">
                            <span><?php echo count($Courses); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="courses-bredgetitle">Courses</p>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php       
}
?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This probably should display the course count `<span><?php echo count($Courses); ?></span>` So what is your actual problem with this code

Comment: What does is do that you dont want it to? Or what does it not do that you do want it to?

Comment: What is core PHP? Do you just mean like, not using a framework? It doesn't look like that core tag has anything to do with PHP.

Comment: Have you check that $courses variable has some value. print_r the variable.
And one more thing where is $id variable declared.

Comment: RiggsFolly its not displaying course count still